# OpenCV Floodfill ImageView and Mat different height and width

Tags: android, opencv, flood-fill

I'm loading an Image (Drawable) into a Mat then convert it to a Bitmap for an ImageView.

```
private void setupImageView() {

    originalImage = new Mat();
    workingImage = new Mat();
    mask = new Mat();

    // Load Drawable into Mat
    try {
        originalImage = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.image, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Convert for needed 3 channels
    Imgproc.cvtColor(originalImage, workingImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);

    // Convert Mat to Bitmap for ImageView
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(workingImage.cols(), workingImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(workingImage, bm);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

    // Create a new Mat Object
    // Mask should be 2 pixels wider and 2 pixels taller than the originalImage
    mask.create(workingImage.rows() + 2, workingImage.cols() + 2, CV_8UC1);
}
```

When clicking inside the ImageView the clicks aren't recognized, because they are outside of the Mat Object for the floodfill Algorithm.

```
@OnTouch(R.id.imageview)
boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        Point seed = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());

        ....
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why are the height and width of the Mat and the ImageView different?
What do I need to change, that my clicks are registered?